# Storing a history list in objective c

Tags: iphone, qr-code, saving-data

I am doing a project to scan qr codes.a.
In this project a *history page* is present in which i have to show the history of user's scans.
It contains URLs only. So I am planning to show the list of urls he scanned previously in a table view.

How can i save the history list? help, please. can I use NSMutable array or something to save the scanned urls like this`[myArray writeToURL:aURL atomically:NO];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes for this you have to create a internel database using sqlite or coredata wherever user scan the qrcode store into database and wherever user wants to see history then fetch from database and display whatever method you use to dispaly

Comment: hiren,can u give me any tutorial links for doing this please?

Comment: try out this tutorials http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2008/10/sqlite-tutorial-selecting-data.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

Your table view needs to implement a UITableViewDataSource to use the NSMutableArray as the source of your table view: (here using *myArray* as the array in this sample code)

```
-(void)saveToHistoryArray:(NSString *)urlAsString {
    [myArray addObject:urlAsString];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
/* insert error checking here */

    return [myArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: magus,thanks for response.but i need to know how can i save the history list in that array

Comment: added a simple method to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/"];
NSString *fullPathToFile = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfile.plist"];
[myArray writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:YES];
```